# need assistance with my Array in visual basic, not adding up correctly

Tags: vb.net

Check the results of “Number of Agencies Needed” after clicking “Select Media and Estimated Fund.” Then select the names of the agencies from the agency listbox on the left and click “Add Agencies.” When the “Add Agencies:” button is clicked, the name of the selected agencies should appear in 
the listbox next to the agency list. Here is the list of agencies, which should be input in the agency listbox on the left.

U-Ad ($350), Striker ($190), NewAd ($250), Samson ($530), J & R ($420), Victory ($120).

When the “Add Agencies:” button is clicked, the results of the calculated estimated cost should appear in the textbox next to “Total Estimated Cost.” 
For example, if you selected “U-Ad” and “Samson,” then the total estimated cost would be $880.00; the results should appear when you click “Add Agencies:” When you add more agencies, such calculated estimated costs should be updated.

```
Public Class Form1

Private Sub btnMediaEstimatedFund_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnMediaEstimatedFund.Click

    Dim interestRate, balance, initialBalance As Double

    txtBoxEstimatedBudget.Enabled = False
    txtBoxAgenciesNeeded.Enabled = False

    If radButtonTraditional.Checked Then

        txtBoxAgenciesNeeded.Text = 3

    ElseIf radButtonEMedia.Checked Then

        txtBoxAgenciesNeeded.Text = 2

    End If

    If checkBoxSavings.Checked Then

        interestRate = 0.07

    ElseIf checkBoxCorporate.Checked Then

        interestRate = 0.05

    ElseIf checkBoxCorporate.Checked And checkBoxSavings.Checked Then

        interestRate = 0.05 * 0.07

    End If

    initialBalance = InputBox("Please Enter a balance between $500.00 and $3000.00")

    If initialBalance > 3000 Then

        InputBox("Please enter a number equal to or below $3000.00 and no less than $500.00")

    ElseIf initialBalance < 500 Then

        InputBox("Please enter a number equal to or above $500.00 and no more than $3000.00")

    Else

        balance = initialBalance * (1 + interestRate)
        txtBoxEstimatedBudget.Text = balance

    End If

End Sub


Private Sub btnAddAgencies_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnAddAgencies.Click

    Dim dict As Dictionary(Of String, Integer) = New Dictionary(Of String, Integer)()
    dict.Add("U-Ad", 350)
    dict.Add("Striker", 190)
    dict.Add("New Ad", 250)
    dict.Add("Samson", 530)
    dict.Add("J & R", 420)
    dict.Add("Victory", 120)

    Dim selectedItems = (From i In lstBoxAgenciesList.SelectedItems).ToArray()
    Dim total As Integer = 0

    For Each selectedItem In selectedItems

        lstBoxSelectedList.Items.Add(selectedItem)
        lstBoxAgenciesList.Items.Remove(selectedItem)

        total += dict(selectedItem)

    Next

    txtBoxEstimatedCost.Text = total.ToString()

End Sub

Private Sub btnGenerateReport_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnGenerateReport.Click

    Dim employeeLevel, year, selectedMedia, numberOfAgencies As String
    Dim today As Date

    today = CStr(dtpToday.Text)
    Name = CStr(txtBoxCreator.Text)
    employeeLevel = CStr(lstBoxResults.Text)
    year = CStr(lstBoxResults.Text)
    selectedMedia = CStr(lstBoxResults.Text)
    numberOfAgencies = CStr(txtBoxAgenciesNeeded.Text)

    dtpToday.Text = FormatDateTime(today, DateFormat.ShortDate)

    If radButtonManager.Checked Then

        employeeLevel = "Manager"

    ElseIf radButtonStaff.Checked Then

        employeeLevel = "Staff"

    End If

    If radButton2015.Checked Then

        year = "2015"

    ElseIf radButton2016.Checked Then

        year = "2016"

    ElseIf radButton2017.Checked Then

        year = "2017"

    End If

    If radButtonTraditional.Checked Then

        selectedMedia = "Traditional Media (TV, Radio)"

    ElseIf radButtonEMedia.Checked Then

        selectedMedia = "New e-Media (SNS, e-Mail)"

    End If

    lstBoxResults.Items.Add("=======================================")
    lstBoxResults.Items.Add(" ")
    lstBoxResults.Items.Add("Date : " & today)
    lstBoxResults.Items.Add(" ")
    lstBoxResults.Items.Add("Reporting Entity : " & Name)
    lstBoxResults.Items.Add(" ")
    lstBoxResults.Items.Add("Level of Employee :  " & employeeLevel)
    lstBoxResults.Items.Add(" ")
    lstBoxResults.Items.Add("=======================================")
    lstBoxResults.Items.Add(" ")
    lstBoxResults.Items.Add("Year" & " " & year & " " & "Budget of Advertising Report")
    lstBoxResults.Items.Add(" ")
    lstBoxResults.Items.Add("=======================================")
    lstBoxResults.Items.Add(" ")
    lstBoxResults.Items.Add("Total Estimated Cost : " & FormatCurrency(txtBoxEstimatedCost.Text))
    lstBoxResults.Items.Add(" ")
    lstBoxResults.Items.Add("Total Estimated Budget : " & FormatCurrency(txtBoxEstimatedBudget.Text))
    lstBoxResults.Items.Add(" ")
    lstBoxResults.Items.Add("Selected Media : " & selectedMedia)
    lstBoxResults.Items.Add(" ")
    lstBoxResults.Items.Add("Number of Agencies Involved : " & numberOfAgencies)
    lstBoxResults.Items.Add(" ")
    lstBoxResults.Items.Add("=======================================")

End Sub
```

End Class

Revised Code!

Comment: Please do not remove the text of your question when you have a solution. Your question text will help future visitors who have the same issue. That is the purpose of Stack Overflow. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this a Windows Form? I'm going to work on the assumption that it is, though it would be transferable across to a WebForms context with a little work.

I am assuming that your ListBox is just full of strings. If so then you could set something up like:

```
    Dim dict As Dictionary(Of String, Integer) = New Dictionary(Of String, Integer)()
    dict.Add("U-AD ($350)", 350)
    dict.Add("Striker ($190)", 190)
    dict.Add("New Ad ($250)", 250)
    dict.Add("Samson ($530)", 530)
    dict.Add("J & R ($420)", 420)
    dict.Add("Victory ($120)", 120)
```

The [Dictionary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508.aspx) is a great collection to know, BTW.

Then, instead of your current code you could do something like:

```
Dim selectedItems = (From i In lstBoxAgenciesList.SelectedItems).ToArray()
Dim total As Integer = 0

For Each selectedItem In selectedItems
    lstBoxSelectedList.Items.Add(selectedItem)
    lstBoxAgenciesList.Items.Remove(selectedItem)
Next

For Each item in lstBoxSelectedList.Items
    total += dict(item)
Next

txtBoxEstimatedCost.Text = total.ToString();
```

Note the difference from your code where we cherry-pick the things to add out of the dictionary rather than try to add the entire list (which is what `While (p < list.Length())` would do). Also, we just assign the `Text` of `txtBoxEstimatedCost` once whereas in your loop it updates at each iteration, which is probably not needed since you only should display the final value.

**Note** that this isn't the best way to do this and you may be better served following an example like [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listcontrol.displaymember.aspx) using the DisplayMember and ValueMember properties.

This makes adding to your list a little harder because you have to add a more complex type (i.e. a class you create) rather than just a String but in the long run I think it is a better approach.

Comment: It almost works! It just does not like the "total += dict[selectedItem].Value" line......

Comment: Actually, never mind it's my mistake and it should just be `total += dict[selectedItem]`

Comment: It still is giving me trouble..... It is giving me this error when I try and move an item to the new listbox "The given key was not present in the dictionary."  And it is point at the "total += dict[selectedItem]"  Sorry to keep bothering you!

Comment: Sorry, I'm used to C# syntax so for VB.NET it should be `total += dict(selectedItem)`. For the other issue this is likely because there is an item in the ListBox whose value does not match the key in the Dictionary code which was provided (e.g. "U-Ad"). I would check how you have defined your ListBox items and ensure that they are spelt exactly the same as in the Dictionary code and that there are no spaces at the string's front or end; when we search for an item in the dictionary it's an exact match-style search (a simplification - in reality there's a little more to it but out of scope here)

Comment: I checked and everything is squared away within the listbox and matching up with the Dictionary.  It is the same error still, a little more info on the error is "KeyNotFoundException was unhanded", "The given key was not present in the dictionary".  And I have changed the line to "total += dict(selectedItem)"  What else could it possibly be talking about??

Comment: Do you get the problem with moving any list box item or is there a particular one which is causing issues?

Comment: Interesting - I have done a little test application and it all works for me without the error...Could you edit your original question and paste in your revised code, hard without seeing it all.

Comment: ok, I just added my entire program! Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: I am working on a project and am kind of stuck in making a sub procedure named FundingResource(). This is what the sub procedure is suppose to do! When the “Select Media and Estimated Fund” button is clicked, Estimated Budget should be calculated depending on your selection of funding resources (one or two). The calculated results should appear in the disabled textbox right next to the “Estimated Budget” textbox. If you selected two resources, each estimated budget should be summarized together. The calculation process should be called a sub procedure defined as FundingResource(balance)

Comment: Sorry, I can't help with your other question (I noticed you posted another SO question about it), just this one. Could you do another edit to your question....I assume that you added the items through the form designer - would you be able to post a screenshot of what that looks like?

Comment: It isn't allowing me to add any photos, but it is in the listbox as follows:

Comment: U-AD ($350), Striker ($190), New Ad ($250), Samson ($530), J & R ($420), Victory ($120).

Comment: And they are listed vertically in the listbox.

Comment: Please see my revised answer - the reason is because your list box elements are things like "U-AD ($350)" but the dictionary key previous was "U-Ad" so they are not the same. They need to match exactly...this is why you're getting the error each time

Comment: Ok, they are showing up in the text box now! The last problem I see if I press U-Ad ($350) it adds 350 to the text box.  And then if I click another selection it is just suppose to add it to the 350 that was already in there... But it isn't.... It is just showing the most recent selection that I click!

Comment: Could you look at this and tell me what you think?

Answer (score 2):

I prefer [List(Of T)](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=list%28of%20t%29&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CDIQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fen-us%2Flibrary%2F6sh2ey19.aspx&ei=2SJNUa_wOqXDyQGds4H4Aw&usg=AFQjCNEDl4T3WgLBndZ1pncFdqEW4rkuog&bvm=bv.44158598,d.aWc) to arrays. I used an Integer since it did not appear you needed a Double type.

```
Dim myList As New List(Of Integer)
myList.Add(350)' etc...
'add the items
Dim total as Integer = myList.Sum()
```